# Font Family Resource from Local Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

I'm trying to access a font that is in a resources folder in my project.  Currently, I have a Font Family resource declared:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="FontFamilyNormal">Resources/#Bank Gothic Medium</FontFamily>
```

This is not working to display the font when I reference this resource.  When I remove the, "Resources/#" and just have Bank Gothic Medium, it works, but I believe it's accessing the font from my OS and not from the resources folder where I wish to access it from.  Is there a way to access the font file from within my resources folder using the FontFamily resource?

Comment: I tried using a pack URI, but that did not work:
`<FontFamily x:Key="FontFamilyNormal">pack://application:,,,/Resources/Bank Gothic Medium.ttf</FontFamily>`

Answer (score 4):

There are rules for embedding fonts into an application, and only fonts that meet the criteria are supported for embedding.

- The font must be a TrueType font (.ttf)
- The font must be licensed to be used in this way.
- The build action for the .ttf file must be "Resource"

I'd suggest testing the font directly on a`TextBlock` before creating a resource out of it.

The first thing to try is the absolute path of the font like this:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="file:///d:/MyProjects/Project/Resources#Bank Gothic Medium">Test</TextBlock>
```

If that works then we can try ditching the full path:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="./Resources/Resources#Bank Gothic Medium">Test</TextBlock>
```

Note: `./resources/` isn't a directory but a special path. You can use a path, but the path would be relative to the control it's used on and there isn't a good way to get to the root of the project.

Finally there is the pack url which should work the best everywhere. It would look like this:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Bank Gothic Medium">Test</TextBlock>
```

`Note: In this last one we used the actual directory for where the font will be.`

It looks like your pretty close!

Comment: Nate, in your Finally statement, the only thing that shows is, "Test".  Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

As described above - *The build action for the .ttf file must be "Resource"*

In your ResourceDirectory, specify

```
<ResourceDictionary>
<FontFamily x:Key="FontKey">pack://application:,,,/FontsFolder/#FontFamilyName</FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can use it as a static or dynamic resource

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontKey}" Text="Some Text" />
```